# React Native. Control a navigator from outside of it

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm new to React Native and I'm trying something like this.

```
const MainNavigator = createSwitchkNavigator({
   Screen1: { screen: Screen1 },
   Screen2: { screen: Screen2 },
});

if (some condition ) MainNavigator.navigate('Screen1');
else MainNavigator.navigate('Screen2');


const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
```

Get the idea?. I'm trying from outside the navigator to force a navigation to one or the other screen depending on some condition or eventually in response of some user tapping a button. This code fails with the message "MainNavigator.navigate is not a function". 
I was assuming that MainNavigator is the same object accessible from inside Screen1 and Screen2 by this.props.navigation.

What approach should I give to this idea?

The final idea is to take the user to a top level screen if logged in or to the auth flow if not.

Thanks.

Comment: if `this.props.navigation` is not null you can navigate to any page inside the App. just do `this.props.navigation.navigate(route);`

Comment: I did navigate from Screen1 to Screen2 and Vice Versa. My issue is how to force a child navigator to navigate.

Comment: just call `this.props.navigation.navigate(route);`

Answer (score 0):

im not sure, but you can try with:

```js
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator(
  { DetailScreen, HomeScreen, OptionsScreen },
  { 
    initialRouteName: condition ? 'HomeScreen': 'DetailScreen', 
    transitionConfig: dynamicModalTransition 
   }
);
```

if you want to move it inside screen, you can use: `this.props.navigation.navigate('RouteName')`